# Remove Empty or Blank line rows from Textarea to Avoid Inserting Blank Rows Into Database

Tags: php, textarea

I have a simple form with a textarea called "negwords".  If there is data in the textarea, each row gets exploded by \n and then I take these values and insert them into the database into a table called "negatives" which only has two fields (id, negative).

The issue is, if an empty or blank carriage return is present and submitted, a blank record appears in my database.

How do I avoid submitting blank or empty lines from a textarea?

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<textarea class="" cols="110" rows="30" name="negwords"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>    
  </div>
  <div id="results">
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST["negwords"]))
{
  //$negative_keyword = explode("\n", $_POST["negwords"]);

  $negative_keyword = array_filter(explode("\n", trim($_POST['negwords'])));
  foreach($negative_keyword as $key => $phrase)
{
    $phrase=trim($phrase);
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO negatives (negative) VALUE ('{$phrase}')";

    mysql_query($sql);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to a SQL-injection -attack. Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mysql_query($sql);` by

```
if (strlen($phrase) > 0) { mysql_query($sql); }
```

And also, as a side note: I highly recommend switching to mysqli from mysql, which is deprecated.

Comment: `strlen(trim($phrase))` would be more suitable.

Comment: strlen counts \r and \n so this is not going to help.

Comment: @heikkim The \n and \r characters should already be gone... Due to the trim!

Comment: @MartyMcVry Yeah, true. Did not see that. That's one of the reasons I don't like nesting functions that deep. When looking quickly over the code you don't see some things.